# Errors in matrix equation?

Tags: equations

I'm getting errors in a matrix equation. When I compile it looks fine, but I'd like to fix them so I don't have to press return for every error at compile time. The code for the equation is:

```
\begin{equation*}

\begin{bmatrix}
U(1,t)  & \cdots & U(n,t) \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
O_{n1} & \cdots & O_{nn} 
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
W(1,1)  & \cdots & W(1,n) \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
W(n,1) & \cdots & W(n,n) 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
D(1,t)  & \cdots & D(n,t) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
I_{n1} & \cdots & I_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}

\end{equation*}
```

The errors I'm getting are related to missing $'s inserted.

Answer (score 8):

If you remove the empty lines after `\begin{equation*}` and before `\end{equation*}` the error messages disappear.

Answer (score 4):

I do not get any message with this one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
U(1,t)  & \cdots & U(n,t) \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
O_{n1} & \cdots & O_{nn} 
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
W(1,1)  & \cdots & W(1,n) \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
W(n,1) & \cdots & W(n,n) 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
D(1,t)  & \cdots & D(n,t) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
I_{n1} & \cdots & I_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're not getting error messages because you don't have blank lines after `\[` and before `\]`, right?

Comment: sure, `amsmath` do not like empty lines inside math environments.

Comment: I thought it might be helpful for readers of this answer if it were stated explicitly what was causing the error to disappear. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The point is a line end is turned into a space by TeX, but two line ends are turned into a `\par`, unless I'm much mistaken. Both answers give a solution removing the two ends of lines. The second one is also reminding me `amsmath` redefines `\[` and `\]` to begin and end `equation*`. In any case, `equation*` clearly enters math mode, as can be seen by looking at its definition. So you can try seeing what happens with `\par` in math mode, and observe that the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
$$\par$$
\end{document}
```

produces:

```
./muMWE.tex:4: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.4 $$\par
          $$
```

which is precisely your error. To know precisely why that happens, you may want to read [the TeXBook](http://web.mit.edu/jgross/www/LaTeX/texbook.pdf) or [TeX by topic](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf). I cannot tell you since I haven't yet read those, but I will read the latter - and have already started.

Comment: @Mico The answer *is* correct; it's TeX that doesn't allow blank lines (or `\par`, which is the same) in math mode. Quoting the TeXbook (Chapter 26 “Summary of math mode”,  page 293): “For example, if a `\par` command appears [in math mode], or if any other inherently non-mathematical command is given, TeX will try to insert a ‘`$`’ just before the offending token; this will lead out of math mode.”

Comment: Just a little detail @egreg: AFAIK `\par` is the same as two end-of-line characters. Under normal circumstances, that means two ASCII return characters (`^^M`). However, if someone decides to change the `\catcode` of `^^M` and sets it to something else, introducing a new end-of-line character, blank lines should not turn to `\par`. Is that right?

Comment: @MickG It's a bit more complicated than that, but, basically, two consecutive characters with category code 5 will be converted to `\par`. Yes, changing the category code of `^^M` from 5 to another value or suppressing `\endlinechar` (with `\endlinechar=-1`) will not convert an empty line into `\par`.

Comment: I guess expanding on "a bit more complicated" could be done by reading one of the linked references, right :)?