# Problem putting matrix operations in an equation

Tags: equations, matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Errors in matrix equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/errors-in-matrix-equation)

I'm trying to use official equation container for the first time, and it's giving me some trouble.  I have this equation of a simple matrix operation, and LaTeX isn't liking it.  What's wrong with this statement?

```
\begin{equation}

    y = \begin{bmatrix}
        T & I
     \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a \\
        e
    \end{bmatrix}

\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't leave blank lines inside environments for displayed math equations:

```
\begin{equation}
    y = \begin{bmatrix}
        T & I
     \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a \\
        e
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

If you want to make your code more readable, then comment out the blank lines:

```
\begin{equation}
%
    y = \begin{bmatrix}
        T & I
     \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a \\
        e
    \end{bmatrix}
%
\end{equation}
```

And, of course, you need to load the `amsmath` package in the preamble to use `bmatrix`:

```
 \usepackage{amsmath}
```