# What's wrong with my formula?

Tags: equations

I have these three equations in another tex file which compiles fine, but when I try to copy and paste those equations, I get an an error. This my code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}  

\begin{equation}    
  10sin(X_{1} + 10) + 10sin(X_{2} + 10) + ... + 10sin(X_{n} + 10)


\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Edit: The error I get is: `! Display math should end with $$.`

Comment: You should use `{}^{\wedge}` instead of `$\^{}$`, and `\sin` instead of `sin`, and `\dots` instead of `...` (needs `\usepackage{amsmath}`. And you don't need `split` at all. However, you probably want to write `X_{2}^{2}` etc., don't you?

Comment: still not working, =\

Comment: Don't leave empty lines in an equation... See [Problem putting matrix operations in an equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65284/5764).

Comment: Strangely, when I add a backslash `\ ` before the `sin`s and removing the blank lines the document compiles. Content in the `equation` environment becomes
`10\sin(X_{1} + 10) + 10\sin(X_{2} + 10) + ... + 10\sin(X_{n} + 10)`

Comment: @KevinC And `...` should be `\dots`

Comment: @egreg: oops, missed that one `;)`