# "File ended while scanning use of \align*"

Tags: errors, equations, align

This is really odd. I have ended all environments. Triple checked them. When I add this last bit of equations using the `align*` environment, all kinds of errors appear. Predominantly, in this case

> "File ended while scanning use of `\align*`"

In case I leave space below the environment and add text or something, this error changes into

> "missing `\endgroup`"

Given that I delete this last bit of equations, all proccesses are exited normally. Of course, this does not let me continue with writing my file.

If it helps, this error started appearing when I first used the `epstopdf` package. Tried deleting it, still the same.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: -@zeroth- thanks for taking time to reply, i will do this asap

Comment: Sorry i wasted your time... i looked meticulusly to the amsmath instructions and got the problem figured out after a long time -@zeroth-

Comment: @konstantine, can you post your solution, and what the mistake was? There might be others with the same problem.

Comment: @konstantine you did not waste my/our time. This is, after all, a Q&A site. So one just have to get into the best way to receive answers. On this site, the welcome link provides all the necessary information to get an answer successfully and fast. Hope to see you again. :)

Comment: This has happened to me when I had a blank line in the environment.

Comment: This happens to lots of people. I've added a warning to the answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98397/enumerate-formulas/98401#98401. I think the question should be reopened and answered here.

Comment: @egreg ... (continuing previous comment) or flagged as a duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/errors-in-matrix-equation.