# strange errors going on in a \end{equation} line

Tags: errors

I was compiling a document containing the following lines (132 to 135):

```
\begin{equation}

\label{shiperfina1}

H_{sh}=\sum \limits_{j=o}^{n} \vec{S}\cdot\textbf{a_j}\vec{I_j}

\end{equation}
```

In the 135 line the following errors show up: `missing $ inserted and missing } inserted`. Furthermore, this errors apears several times in the log (26 times to be exact).

In the previous lines it's everything correct.

What do I do?

Thanks.

Comment: LaTeX doesn't like blank lines inside an `equation` environment.

Comment: You should not leave blank lines in the `equation` environment

Comment: And [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Errors in matrix equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9283/5764)

Comment: try `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf`, or at least embolden the two letters separately to get the underscore out of a likely "text"-specific context